# Line breaks in pop up text box

Tags: carto

I'm having trouble editing text in a pop up window for a layer I have in CARTO.

[image]

The data in the pop up window comes from an Excel spreadsheet. I would like to know if there is a way for me to create line breaks in the window so that the separate terms in there remain separated on their own lines. For example, the first term is 'genesis electric skateboard' and the second term is 'abigail ratchford skateboard.' I need those terms on their own lines, but as is they are running together.

I tried creating line breaks in the Excel cell using Alt+Enter but that doesn't make a difference when I import that sheet to this layer.

I would also like to know how to adjust the width of the pop up window so I can fit the entire term like 'genesis electric skateboard' on one line without it wrapping to a line below.

I would also like to know how to adjust the title of the pop up window to get rid of the underscores between the words TOP 5 GOOGLE SEARCHES.

Answer (score 1):

The CARTO pop-ups render the content of the cells as HTML text format.

I would recommend writing the HTML tag <[br](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp)> in the cells text to create the break lines when the information of the cell is displayed within the infowindow.

For example, in the dataset view you write `some<br/>text`, the infowindow will show

some
text

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It worked! Do you know how to make the pop-up box wider so it can fit something as long as "Genesis electric skateboard" on a single line without wrapping the text?

Comment: If the answer @oriolbx gave you solved your issue, marked as solved. Please post this new question on another thread.